# Angular 4 page doesn't load

Tags: angular

I'm learning angular 4 now and bought a book about it.
Unfortunately there are some errors in the book and i'm making some too, so the code doesn't run at the first try. But until now I could solve them by my self. But now I'm getting some errors and the page doesn't load, and I don't now why.
In this book we create a webshop, for pizza. The last thing I did was adding a login system, at this poiunt the app worked, but then there where some changes made in the book and now the page don't load and there are errors in the browser console.

```
AppComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR Error: No provider for Account!
at injectionError (reflective_errors.ts:71) [angular]
at noProviderError (reflective_errors.ts:105) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (reflective_injector.ts:500) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.ts:543) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.ts:404) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.ts:349) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.get (module.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.getInternal (module.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (ng_module_factory.ts:141) [angular]
at resolveDep (provider.ts:504) [angular]
at createClass (provider.ts:368) [angular]
at createDirectiveInstance (provider.ts:192) [angular]
at createViewNodes (view.ts:291) [angular]
at createRootView (view.ts:223) [angular]



AppComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR CONTEXT
DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 1, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object}

Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for Account! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No provider for Account!
at injectionError (reflective_errors.ts:71) [angular]
at noProviderError (reflective_errors.ts:105) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (reflective_injector.ts:500) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.ts:543) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.ts:404) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.ts:349) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.get (module.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.getInternal (module.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (ng_module_factory.ts:141) [angular]
at resolveDep (provider.ts:504) [angular]
at createClass (provider.ts:368) [angular]
at createDirectiveInstance (provider.ts:192) [angular]
at createViewNodes (view.ts:291) [angular]
at createRootView (view.ts:223) [angular] Error
at injectionError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:1238:86) [angular]
at noProviderError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:1276:12) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:2777:19) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:2816:25) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:2748:25) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:2617:21) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.get (ng:///AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:236:129) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.getInternal (ng:///AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:415:51) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:3563:44) [angular]
at resolveDep (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:10931:45) [angular]
at createClass (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:10792:91) [angular]
at createDirectiveInstance (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:10628:37) [angular]
at createViewNodes (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:11978:49) [angular]
at createRootView (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:11883:5) [angular]

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Account!
Error
at injectionError (reflective_errors.ts:71) [angular]
at noProviderError (reflective_errors.ts:105) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (reflective_injector.ts:500) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.ts:543) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.ts:404) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.ts:349) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.get (module.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.getInternal (module.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (ng_module_factory.ts:141) [angular]
at resolveDep (provider.ts:504) [angular]
at createClass (provider.ts:368) [angular]
at createDirectiveInstance (provider.ts:192) [angular]
at createViewNodes (view.ts:291) [angular]
at createRootView (view.ts:223) [angular]
at injectionError (reflective_errors.ts:71) [angular]
at noProviderError (reflective_errors.ts:105) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (reflective_injector.ts:500) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.ts:543) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.ts:404) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.ts:349) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.get (module.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.getInternal (module.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (ng_module_factory.ts:141) [angular]
at resolveDep (provider.ts:504) [angular]
at createClass (provider.ts:368) [angular]
at createDirectiveInstance (provider.ts:192) [angular]
at createViewNodes (view.ts:291) [angular]
at createRootView (view.ts:223) [angular]
at :3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:654:33 [<root>]
```

Edit:

So here is the code

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {AuthService} from './login/ts/services/auth.service'

@Component({
selector: 'pizzaconnection',
templateUrl: 'app/app.html',
styleUrls: ['app/css/styles.css'],
})

export class AppComponent{

private items: MenuItem[];

constructor(private _router:Router, private _authService:AuthService) {

    localStorage.removeItem('auth_token');

        this.items = [{
        label: 'Speisekarte',
        icon: 'fa fa-cutlery',
        routerLink: ['']
    },
    {
        label: 'Warenkorb',
        icon: '',
        routerLink: ['/cart']
    }]
}

logout() { this._authService.logout(); }

login() { this._router.navigate(['login']); }

isLoggedIn() { return this._authService.isLoggedIn(); }
```

}

app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {InputTextModule, ButtonModule, MenubarModule, DataGridModule, PanelModule, 
    DataListModule, GrowlModule, DataTableModule, DropdownModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {routing} from './app.routes';
import {PizzaListComponent} from './pizza/ts/components/pizzalist.component'
import {HttpModule, JsonpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {PizzaListService} from './pizza/ts/services/pizzalist.service';
import {PizzaDetailService} from './pizza/ts/services/pizzadetail.service';
import {PizzaDetailComponent} from './pizza/ts/components/pizzadetail.component';
import {CartComponent} from './cart/ts/components/cart.component';
import {CheckoutComponent} from './checkout/ts/components/checkout.component';
import {Cart} from './cart/ts/models/cart.model';
import {CheckoutService} from './checkout/ts/services/checkout.service';
import {OrderOptionComponent} from './order-option/ts/components/order-option.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/ts/components/login.component';
import {AuthService} from './login/ts/services/auth.service';
import {Account} from './login/ts/models/account.model';
import {ConfirmationComponent} from './confirmation/ts/components/confirmation.component'
import {AccountCreatorComponent} from './account-creator/ts/components/account-creator.component';
import {AccountCreatorService} from './account-creator/ts/services/account-creator.service';

@NgModule({
imports:        [BrowserModule,
                 InputTextModule,
                 ButtonModule,
                 FormsModule,
                 BrowserAnimationsModule, 
                 routing,
                 MenubarModule, 
                 HttpModule,
                 JsonpModule,
                 DataGridModule,
                 PanelModule,
                 DataListModule,
                 GrowlModule,
                 DataTableModule,
                 DropdownModule],
declarations:   [AppComponent,
                 PizzaListComponent,
                 PizzaDetailComponent,
                 CartComponent,
                 CheckoutComponent,
                 OrderOptionComponent,
                 LoginComponent,
                 ConfirmationComponent,
                 AccountCreatorComponent],
bootstrap:      [AppComponent],
providers:      [PizzaListService,
                 PizzaDetailService,
                 Cart,
                 CheckoutService,
                 AuthService,
                 Account,
                 AccountCreatorService]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

This are the files of the project, maybe it might be helpfull.

I will post the link to the pics in the comments

Comment: can you post your code too.. looks like you didn't declare the providers inside component metadata or in NgModule

Comment: Of which file(s) do you want the code? Because the whole project contains about 20 files.

Comment: AppComponent, module, the account service you are trying to use from

Comment: I posted the code at the edit of my post.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bo9g4.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/v68Iq.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCDiD.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/smaWF.png

Comment: In which component are you using Account service

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the logs, this might work
Import the service or any providers and declare them in the providers of component metadata

```
import {Servicename} from serviceURL
@Component({
  providers : [Servicename]
})
```

Other way is to declare the dependency in NgModule

```
@NgModule({
 providers : [Servicename]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to what I see in the screenshots Account is not a service and you have to add the Account in the providers Array only if it is a service.

Comment: So I removed Account from th eproviders array, but the errors are still there. I uploadet this project to github. So if somebody is interessented. https://github.com/jupper/PizzaConnectionClient

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem is solved. There was a typo in ath.service.ts

```
import {Account} from '..//models/account.model';
```

changed it to

```
import {Account} from '../models/account.model';
```

now its fine. Thank you.